# Query on Joins - Each column is a key in other tables. Need to join and fetch the corresponding column value

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am having a problem framing a query with joins. Below you can find my tables structure and data.

Tabl1 (Contains ID's and Code's. The description for these codes is present in tabl3.)

| ID1 | ID2 | CD1 | CD2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | MAC | BMW |
| 1 | 102 | XPS | AUD |

Tabl2 (Contains Customer names)

| tab_id1 | tab_id2 | Cust_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | Cust Name 1 |
| 1 | 102 | Cust Name 2 |

Tabl3 (Contains Description of codes present in tabl1.)

| tab_id1 | Code | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MAC | Apple laptop |
| 1 | XPS | Dell laptop |
| 1 | BMW | BMW Auto |
| 1 | AUD | Audi Auto |

Tabl1 holds the codes in the columns cd1, cd2. For these codes the description is defined in tabl3. So I need to join tabl3 and get the description values and display it. So I need to write a query that should have the following output.

```
id1, id2, cust_name, cd1 ||' - '|| description for cd1, cd2 || ' - ' ||description for cd2.
```

I tried the below query, but I'm getting multiple rows (4 rows whereas the output should have only 2 rows).

```sql
select
    t1.id1,
    t1.id2,
    t2.cust_name,
    t1.cd1,
    t3.description,
    t1.cd2,
    t3.description
from
    tabl1 t1,
    tabl2 t2,
    tabl3 t3
where
    t1.id2 = t2.tab_id2
    AND t1.id1 = t3.tab_id1
    AND t1.id1 = t2.tab_id1
    AND (
        t3.code = t1.cd1
        or t3.code = t1.cd2
    );
```

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names (above, say, 2), you can be confident that your schema design is sub-optimal. See about normalisation and fix your schema.

Answer (score 1):

the last join with table3 makes two rows for each match in code , you need to do join with table3 two times , eachtime with code 1 and code 2:

```
select
    t1.id1,
    t1.id2,
    t2.cust_name,
    t1.cd1,
    t3_1.description,
    t1.cd2,
    t3_1.description
from
    tabl1 t1
join tabl2 t2 
    on t1.id2 = t2.tab_id2
    AND t1.id1 = t2.tab_id1
join tabl3 t3_1 
    on t1.id1 = t3_1.tab_id1
    AND t3_1.code = t1.cd1
join tabl3 t3_2
    on t1.id1 = t3_2.tab_id1
    AND t3_2.code = t1.cd2
```

Comment: The response above is perfect, now just for your knowledge, there are many types of [joins](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_join.asp), you should check what fit's you the best.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The query works good. Jus another doubt, my real world table structure has 25 columns(like cd1,cd2... cd25) so as per above solution I would have to create 25 table aliases of t3. so how would the query perform in terms of performance? Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes , you will need 25 joins and performance would be poor of course and Its because of bad design of database , instead of saving data in rows you are saving data in columns and that is not good for database performance since RDMS are designed to work with rows

Comment: Thank you @eshirvana. Jus thinking aloud.. I think I should make one DB call to save all 25 code and descriptions in say java hashMap(its a java based application) for that particular user and then i can avoid all 25 additional joins and replace the codes with description in Java. I think this would perform better than adding 25 joins to my sql query.

Comment: I think still joins in sql would be faster but give it a shot